# How to read the content of the file using FleReader while upload multiple file upload in react js

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, filereader

I tried to upload Multiple files and wants to read the content of the file for encrypt the data.
I can able to read the single file properly , but I can't do it while upload multiple files am getting error reader is busy.
If I create new Filereader while onloadend it gives me null value of content.

### React JS - sample code:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
class FilReaderComp extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

}}
upLoadFileFolderFunc(e){
e.preventDefault();
let fileitemsList = e.target.files;
for (let i = 0; i < fileitemsList.length; i++) {
  let fileitems = fileitemsList[i];
  reader.onloadend = this.handleFileRead;
  reader.readAsText(fileitems);
  }
}

handleFileRead = (e) => {
const content = reader.result; here am reading content of the file

//here doing my function after getting content
}
render(){
return(
<input  type="file" className="custom-file-input" style={{display:"hide"}}
            onChange={this.upLoadFileFolderFunc} multiple/>
);}

export default withRouter(FilReaderComp);
```

Comment: Please include a code sample of how you're constructing the `FileReader` and the context around it.

Comment: You have to use multiple FileReader objects or wait for the reader to complete each time before you read another file.

Comment: I tried with multiple Filereader object it's not working. Please explain how to wait to wait for reader to complete each time before read another file

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple readers you have to create them in the for loop and access them via the event object(e.targrt) in the callback.

```
class FilReaderComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }
  upLoadFileFolderFunc(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let fileitemsList = e.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < fileitemsList.length; i++) {
      let fileitems = fileitemsList[i];
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = this.handleFileRead;
      reader.readAsText(fileitems);
    }
  }

  handleFileRead = (e) => {
    const content = e.targrt.result; //here am reading content of the file

    //here doing my function after getting content
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <input  type="file" className="custom-file-input" style={{display:"hide"}}
            onChange={this.upLoadFileFolderFunc} multiple/>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(FilReaderComp);
```

Comment: I tried with create Filereader loop function. But I can't able to get the actual data it's like numm value while read content.